# WPF XAML: Setting line stroke via another control's trigger

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a close (and minimise) button in my WPF program. I use 2 lines in order to create the 'X' look of the close button. This works absolutely fine.

At the moment, the way it works is I have a Grid parent, with the two lines and a transparent button as children. The colour of the lines is a yellowy colour (hex #14FF1A) and as I said before, a transparent background. When the user's mouse is over the button I want the background to turn to the yellowy colour, and the two lines to turn black. I have successfully turned the button's background yellow, but cannot turn the lines black.

I am using styles, here is my button style code.

```
<Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                    <Border x:Name="border" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                        <ContentPresenter x:Name="contentPresenter" Focusable="False" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                    </Border>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsDefaulted" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="border" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}}"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="border" Value="{StaticResource Button.MouseOver.Background2}"/>
                            <Setter Property="TextElement.Foreground" TargetName="contentPresenter" Value="Black"/>
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="border" Value="{StaticResource Button.MouseOver.Border}"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="border" Value="{StaticResource Button.Pressed.Background2}"/>
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="border" Value="{StaticResource Button.Pressed.Border}"/>
                            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" TargetName="border" Value="0,0,0,0"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="border" Value="{StaticResource Button.Disabled.Background2}"/>
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="border" Value="{StaticResource Button.Disabled.Border}"/>
                            <Setter Property="TextElement.Foreground" TargetName="contentPresenter" Value="{StaticResource Button.Disabled.Foreground}"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

And here is what I have tried already (using data triggers binding to the button's 'IsMouseOver').

```
<Style x:Key="LineStyle1" TargetType="{x:Type Line}">
<Style.Triggers>
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=parent, Path=IsMouseOver}" Value="True">
<Setter Property="Stroke" Value="Black"/>
</DataTrigger>
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=parent, Path=IsMouseOver}" Value="False">
<Setter Property="Stroke" Value="#14FF1A"/>
</DataTrigger>
 </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Regards

Comment: What if, instead of having a transparent button inside your parent grid, add your lines (and eventually text) directly to the content of the button? Something like `<Button Background="Transparent"><Grid>my content ...</Grid><Button.Style>...</Button>`. Then, in the style for your lines, you can bind the triggers to `<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsMouseOver, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Button}}" Value="True">`